# WebGL build refuses to work on iOS devices

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, deployment, webgl, unity-webgl

My recent WebGL builds fails to load on iOS devices. The builds work fine on other devices, but I cannot get it to work on iOS.
Here are the games link - https://html5.gamedistribution.com/ad4c6d8aca7e4ff3b5386f938af1f19a/
and https://revision.gamedistribution.com/5e03b893d2584b59b2d6278d55b6abd7/?correlator=1689348314577

Sorry if you got hit with ads. But for now, I cannot really host the games on another place.
I don't have an iOS device, but one of the testers browsers showed this-

[ERROR message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5gIy.png)

Another note, I have to build the game without Compression. No Gzip, no Brotli, just disabled.

This is super frustrating, now that I am building games for mobile too, it just doesn't wanna work.
Any help would be highly appreciated!

Thank you!

I looked up many solutions, kinda found that it can be because of memory problems that iOS have when dealing with WebGL.

Comment: Safari on IOS doesnt support everything -   so, I have a bunch of games on my site, the 2d ones seem to work, its the 3d ones that dont.. theres clearly stuff in it it doesnt like.. like any platform it has an element of limitation.

Comment: Personally i get "WebAssembly streaming compilation failed! This can happen for example if
"Content-Encoding" HTTP header is incorrectly enabled on the server for file Build/Drag RACE!
URP.wasm, but the file is not pre-compressed on disk (or vice versa). Check the Network tab in browser Devtools to debug server header configuration." suggestion then is website setup issue

Comment: Does that mean it can maybe run if hosted on another website? And if it's a HTTP header problem, then how come the wasm is running on another platforms? The strange thing is a previous game of mine did run on iOS. I updated Unity, yes, but downgrading is a stupid move right now. OR is Unity actually somehow including a header... somehow?

Comment: Older versions (like 2017 i think) were different. So. Dont hold me to when but at one point. Build.js actually was Build.js.gz or bz and they declared you had to setup your website so it sent the headers to make it work.  Somethings are more forgiving i guess but again recently it changed again. A lot of it is not the blatent bit  otherwise it wouldnt start the load screen. Its more the after. It annoyed people for years. There was like a year where all of us doing webgl games had to follow some sacred post on how because it defied logic. Now. All different

Comment: Oh... never thought I would hear such things here... it's like a comprehensive grandpa type of thing- 'back in the days, we used to travel 2 hours to get to school, but now it's all different..*pause*.. All different."
Haha... jokes aside, but do you work with Unity webgl now? I don't exactly know what you're talking about, but I believe that 'Build.js.gz' or *'br' is just compressing formats, and it still exists. But I did mention 'I need to build without compression'. Please correct me if I am wrong, as WebGL is still kinda a web thing, and I am not quite familiar with web stuffs.

Comment: yes I still do webgl now. And hence I can tell you that the config requirements changed again, but again, they are very specific.  And while for example 99.9% of web servers serve .gz files as gzip, unity needs specific lines added or it just doesnt seem to work.  you dont need to build without compression you just need to set the web setup right - and unity have documented it

Comment: So, how does the info will help me fix the iOS issue? I got the thing that gzip and brotli compression will only work if you setup your website right, and I kinda knew that already. Also, will compression magically fix my problem?

Umm... kinda curious, is there more to setting up the site, than setting the http header 'content-encoding' to 'gzip' or 'br'? Might be a stupid question, but yes.

Comment: You can only fix one thing at a time. But its refusing to work because it sees that error. Once you get past that you can look at any future errors. As i said. Some things are more forgiving

Comment: Since we are talking about compression, I tried to dig up a little, and found 'Decompression fallback'. In short, if there are not proper compression setup on a web server, it will just not run. So, disabling compression should make it work, right? Right?? Again, apparently 'Decompression fallback' checkbox in Unity adds a JAVASCRIPT decompressor. Hmm.... but is this same as adding 'disabled compression' files on top of the other files, or different? They do actually have different file extensions. Oof... I just wanna make my games work on iOS. Also, can you again check the 2nd website?

Comment: The second one starts loading. Looks like it got there changes url. Kinda does the same and then says cant load this page. So you youre on your own with that hot mess

Comment: Haha... okay whatever... will see. Also, the changing url is probably iOS safari redirecting to an error page, rather than just failing to load and showing an alert like a normal web browser. I believe.

Comment: Maybe. But it does 2 different unity loads so who knows

Comment: So, safari just tries to reload the page, then fails again, then just shows the error message. That's it. The webserver is not set up right, okay. Let's keep that. I just uploaded the same thing on itch.io... does this work? https://realinspirer.itch.io/temp on iOS? It's itch.io, so most likely no problems with headers for gzip.